# When using DT::renderDataTable, how do I access which rows are filtered when server = TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am working on a Shiny app to let users select columns, filter rows, and download the result.  I am using Data Tables to do this.  The data file is moderately large and using client-side processing results in a fairly significant slowdown; however, using server side processing I am unable to get access to the filtered dataset.

In other words, when server=FALSE in renderDataTable(), input$foo_rows_all returns all filtered rows but when server=TRUE input$foo_rows_all returns just the rows on the currently displayed page, not all rows.  How can I get access to all filtered rows when server = TRUE.

An example that shows the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

dat<-data.frame(letters=c(rep("A",15),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Returns filtered data
  output$dat_false <- renderDataTable(dat,filter = "top",server = FALSE)
  #Returns just the currently visible values 
  output$dat_true <- renderDataTable(dat,filter = "top",server = TRUE)

  #This code modified from: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/
  output$x5 = renderPrint({
    cat('\n\nAll rows with server = TRUE:\n\n')
    cat(input$dat_true_rows_all, sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nAll rows with server = FALSE:\n\n')
    cat(input$dat_false_rows_all, sep = ', ')
  })
})

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(verbatimTextOutput('x5')),
      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("dat_true"),
                dataTableOutput("dat_false"))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Could it be that this issue has been resolved with later versions of DT? Just tested your example, and both server= TRUE and server=FALSE work as intended, and in the same way ...

Answer (score 1):

You have the `input$data_true_search_columns` and `input$data_true_search` variables to work with.  So, for example you could write a function like this to get the selected rows (note I am using `fromJSON` to convert the json, but you could use `chartr("[]", "()", ...)` or similar to do it manually.  I don't know if this is the proper way, and to deal with the numeric range selections you would need to modify the function to deal with those.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)

dat<-data.frame(letters=c(rep("A",15),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)))

activeRows <- function(cols) {
    active <- which(cols!='')
    if (!length(active)) return( seq_len(nrow(dat)) )
    vals <- lapply(cols[active], fromJSON)
    which(
      Reduce("&", lapply(seq_along(vals), function(i) dat[,i] %in% vals[[i]])))
}

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Returns filtered data
  output$dat_false <- renderDataTable(dat,filter = "top",server = FALSE)
  #Returns just the currently visible values 
  output$dat_true <- renderDataTable(dat,filter = "top",server = TRUE)

  #This code modified from: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/
  output$x5 = renderPrint({
    cat('\n\nAll rows with server = TRUE:\n\n')
    cat(activeRows(input$dat_true_search_columns), sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nAll rows with server = FALSE:\n\n')
    cat(input$dat_false_rows_all, sep = ', ')
  })
})

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(verbatimTextOutput('x5')),
      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("dat_true"),
                dataTableOutput("dat_false"))
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui,server)
```